# Мобильный сайт в мобильное приложение

Tags: android, html, css, visual-studio

Есть сайт с адаптивной версткой, хочу ее сделать под мобильные устройства хотя бы на андроид, но с немного измененным CSS. Нашел вот такое вот решение c [Web App template](http://wat.codeplex.com/) для Visual Basic.Однако с ним очень много хлопот с установкой пишет что нет Framework , но я устанавливал его для Windows 10 (у меня windows 10). Подскажите что делать , может есть другое решение?.

Comment: Я так понимаю ты хочешь подгружать сайт с помощью приложения? Если да, то посмотри android webkit. Вот есть уроки http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/mybrowser.php

Comment: Да хочу, но еще хочу немного изменить из дизайн с CSS , возможно ли так?

Comment: Да какие проблемы. Твои сайт будет висеть на сервере и соответственно отображаться в браузере. Твое приложение просто подгружает его из интернета. Любое изменение CSS, JavaScript HTML, php отобразится и на том как он выглядит в приложении.

Comment: Я хотел донести мысль что в приложении сайт будет с чуть с другим дизайном, не таким как он будет отображаться в самом браузере телефона.